# Python selenium # Chrome extension - waspinspector-analytics: opens waspinspector page instead driver.get(url)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Setup:

- Python
- selenium
- (driver for Chrome and Firefox)
- for chrome install adswerve-datalayer-inspec

code:

```
import os 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

dirExtensionsChrome = "/home/user/Chrome_extensions/"

adswerve_datalayer = "public-adswerve-datalayer==kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom.crx"
waspinspector = "waspinspector-analytics-s==niaoghengfohplclhbjnjheodgkejpih.crx"

url = 'https://tealium.com/de/'

testing = False 
timeWait = 90

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['goog:loggingPrefs'] = {'performance': 'ALL'}

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()

extChrome = [adswerve_datalayer, waspinspector]
for ext in extChrome:
    chrome_options.add_extension( os.path.join( dirExtensionsChrome, ext ) ) 

browser = webdriver.Chrome( options=chrome_options, desired_capabilities=caps , ) 
browser.set_page_load_timeout(60)

browser.get( url)
```

error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from no such window
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Without waspinspector the url is loaded (like it should).
With the extension waspinspector not the URL/Homepage of tealium opens but the [WASP](http://www.webanalyticssolutionprofiler.com/chrome/installed/?utm_source=plugin&utm_medium=chrome&utm_campaign=wasp&v=1.4.2#axzz6hSBKXKZH) page.
How can this behavior be stopped?

[image]